# Blog is autoreloading when visited (with a scriptblocker on mac)?

Tags: bug, blog

When I visit the following link I get eyecancer from millisecond reloads and am redirected after a short duration to a page that tells my that there were to many requests from my IP:

(epilepsy warning)

http://security.blogoverflow.com/2013/09/about-secure-password-hashing/

edit:

this problem occured on a mac, using chrome and some script blocker (shield symbol). I don't know which script blocker exactly, I have to look it up monday. The scriptblocker symbol was blinking aswell with every reload.

edit2:

I just saw that there are user-comments at the bottom, maybe this was a code injection "attack" of some kind ? I can only say on monday, whether the problem is still existant.

Maybe the scriptblocker isn't properly escaping something or executing some html/javascript for some reason ?

The problem is still persisting, but it seems it's an addon problem as the same problem occurs on amazon.com.

The addon is "ScriptBlock".

This is the console output shortly before quitting, I'm not able to provide network debug data as I cannot prevent the page from reloading and the requests are deleted on reload (no option available to stop that in chrome).

```
Uncaught TypeError: q.setAttribute is not a function(…)
(anonymous function) @ jquery.min.js:2
(anonymous function) @jquery.min.js:2
(anonymous function) @ jquery.min.js:4
seAuthentication.js:34 
Uncaught ReferenceError: jQuery is not defined(…)
(anonymous function) @ seAuthentication.js:34
security.blogoverflow.com/:53 
Uncaught ReferenceError: jQuery is not defined(…)
(anonymous function) @ security.blogoverflow.com/:53
security.blogoverflow.com/:612 
Uncaught ReferenceError: jQuery is not defined(…)
(anonymous function) @ security.blogoverflow.com/:612
Navigated to http://security.blogoverflow.com/2013/09/about-secure-password-hashing/
```

Comment: Seems to work fine for me.  Are you still seeing this behavior?

Comment: I edited to include my os and browser, on my windows machine I'm not seeing the behaviour. I can only say it on monday.

Comment: I just saw that there are user-comments at the bottom, maybe this was a code injection "attack" of some kind ? I can only say on monday, whether the problem is still existant.